# Using alias without AS

Tags: postgresql, alias

I found the following query from a reference note and I could see naming `lineitem` table as `l1` and `lineitem` table as `l2`.

```
select avg(l_extendedprice) from lineitem l1
where l_extendedprice =
(select min(l_extendedprice) from lineitem l2
where l1.l_orderkey = l2.l_orderkey);
```

Is this a valid aliasing method, without explicitly using `AS`? If this is not aliasing in Postgres, what is this convention?

Comment: Yes, you can alias without AS. I am not sure which db's wont let you do this.

Comment: @DougCoats is there any difference in using AS for aliasing or just do it without AS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The SQL standard lets you use aliases with or without `AS`.

The difference is that without `AS`, you cannot use a PostgreSQL keyword as alias, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-COLUMN-LABELS). So it's safer to always use `AS`.